# How should I provide library binaries to developers?

Tags: c++, github, dependencies, cross-platform, binaries

I want to make it easy for others to work on my repository. However, since some of the compiled dependencies are over 100mb in size, I cannot include them into the repository. Github rejects those files.

What is the best way to handle large binaries of dependencies? Building the libraries from source is not easy under Windows and takes hours. I don't want every developer to struggle with this process.

Comment: You don't really have a choice if your project is open source. Trying to package pre-built binaries isn't a good idea, due to compiler and library version differences from machine to machine.

Comment: @dauphic I used sub directories for all build combinations like `bin/windows-vs12-x86-debug/v8.lib` for example. Some of my libraries aren't natively compatible with some compilers and I can't expect every other developer to apply those workarounds again.

Answer (score 1):

I've recently been working on using Ivy (http://ant.apache.org/ivy/) with C++ binaries.  The basic idea is that you build the binaries for every build combination.  You will then zip each build combination into a file with a name like mypackage-windows-vs12-x86-debug.zip.  In your ivy.xml, you will associate each zip file with exactly one configuration (ex: windows-vs12-x86-debug).  Then you publish this package of multiple zip files to an Ivy repo.  You can either host the repo yourself or you can try to upload to an existing Ivy repo.  You would create a package of zip files for each dependency, and the ivy.xml files will describe the dependency chain among all the packages.

Then, your developers must set up Ivy.  In their ivy.xml files, they will list your package as a dependency, along with the configuration they need (ex: windows-vs12-x86-debug).  They will also need to add an ivy resolve/retrieve step to their build.  Ivy will download the zip files for your package and everything that your package depends on.  Then they will need to set up unzip & move tasks in their builds to extract the binaries you are providing, and put them in places their build is expecting.

Ivy's a cool tool but it is definitely streamlined for Java and not for C++.  When it's all set up, it's pretty great.  However, in my experience as a person who is not really familiar with DevOps at all, integrating it into a C++ build has been challenging.  I found that it was easiest to create simple ant tasks that do the required ivy actions, then use my "regular" build system (make) to call those ant tasks when needed.

So I should also mention that the reason I looked into using Ivy was that I was implementing this in a corporate environment where I couldn't change system files.  If you and your developers can do that, you may be better off with a RPM/APT system.  You'd set up a repo and get your developers to add your repo to the appropriate RPM/APT config file.  Then they would run commands like `sudo apt-get install mypackage` and apt-get would do all the work of downloading and installing the right files in the right places.  I don't know how this would work on Windows, maybe someone has created a windows RPM/APT client.

Comment: Ivy sounds interesting, I'll take a look at it. Unfortunately, there is no package manager on Windows. Handling cross platform dependencies would be so much easier.